# Solving Travelling Salesman with SFLA

Tags: algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I have to implement the SFLA for travelling salesman, and here I am considering each frog (a feasible solution) as an array (with its size as the number of cities), containing cities ordered in the way they would be travelled. I can't figure how to update the worst solution in each memeplex using the best solution. I can't grasp how to relate the two. The paper I am referring to:

> X. h. Luo, Y. Yang and X. Li, "Solving TSP with Shuffled Frog-Leaping
>   Algorithm," 2008 Eighth International Conference on Intelligent
>   Systems Design and Applications, Kaohsiung, 2008, pp. 228-232. doi:
>   10.1109/ISDA.2008.346 keywords: {search problems;travelling salesman problems;TSP;complex combinatorial optimization problem;efficient
>   mathematical function;global search capability;memeplex;memetic
>   meta-heuristic algorithm;shuffled frog-leaping
>   algorithm;submemeplex;traveling salesman problem;Ant colony
>   optimization;Benchmark testing;Cities and towns;Design
>   engineering;Educational institutions;Intelligent
>   systems;Prototypes;Space exploration;Traveling salesman problems;Water
>   resources;optimization;shuffled frog leaping algorith;traveling
>   salesman problem}, URL:
>   http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4696466&isnumber=4696419

Answer (score 0):

This part of the algorithm in mainly intuitive. You just have to make the worst frog closer to the best frog in order to improve its fitness function. There is no one certain way but here is an example

```
new = worst + ( best - worst ) * random() 

best = [1 , 5, 21, 10, 8]
worst = [12, 3, 9, 18, 4]
diff = [-11, 2, -12, -8, 4]
random = 0.3 // 0 < random < 1 
new = [8.7, 3.6, 5.4, 15.6, 5.2] // adapt this frog to your space
                                 // round it to int, remove duplicates, ...
new = [9, 3, 5, 16, 4]
```

As you can see the new frog is closer to the best and we hope that its fitness has been improved if not we have to create a new frog.

One other way would be to use [cross-over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossover_(genetic_algorithm)), choose a crossover point a replace the items before\after that point with items from the best solution:

```
BEST :  [1,2,4,5,3] 
WORST : [4,3,2,1,5]
NEW :   [1,2,2,1,5]
            ^
// crossover point
```

Each of these methods has its pros and cons and you have to choose which method fits your problem more.

Comment: Can you please explain what're you taking in the best and worst arrays? It's unclear to me how the new frog is closer to the best one

Comment: best is the frog with maximum value for fitness function in that memplex and worst is the frog with minimum value. What did you meant by best solution and worst solution in your question?

Comment: I meant that I couldn't understand what values you took in the solution containers. In my case I'm considering taking the cities, and the best frog will have such order of cities which will minimize the tour length. Now in your example, I couldn't see how subtracting each element of the worst frog with the corresponding index of the best frog would work to improve the fitness (decrease the tour length) of the worst frog, when it doesn't share the same cities as the best frog or the new one.

Comment: I'm saying that we take cities in some order say: BEST : [1,2,4,5,3] WORST : [4,3,2,1,5]. Now by the updation policy,  we have to use the best frog to somehow improve the worst one, and that's what I can't grasp here. That how would I change the city order in the worst one to make it closer to the best one.

Comment: You can randomly replace the items in worst with items in best. There is no certain way as it greatly depends on the application. You just have to test various ways and check which one works best.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! I feel I have somewhere to start with now

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on it. The multiplication with random number that is a trational way will not work here. The cross over technique will do the job. Keep selecting the no of cities randomly until you find the optimal.
In big problems where no of cities are more than 10 you can design potential optimal solutions for search.

Comment: Welcome to SO, This is not an answer to the question, you can add it as a comment once you have enough reputations